# Toggling Full Screen view on Key press in Flash via Actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Below is my code aimed at getting my flash content to toggle between full screen view and normal view on press of the spacebar key, so far no compiler errors yet does not work.

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stage.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, toggleScreenview);
function toggleScreenview(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
    } else {
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE,this example work with space key, if full screen go to normal and if normal go to full screen

your solution is:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, toggleScreenview);
function toggleScreenview(e:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
    {

        if(stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL)
        {
            stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
        }

        else
        {
            stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
        }
    }
}
```

**Good Luck**